# How can I pass multiple parameters to an ObjectDataProvider dynamically (in code)

Tags: c#, wpf

I am new to WPF and would like to know how I can pass multiple parameters to an `ObjectDataProvider` in code behind.

Xaml (works fine):

```
<ObjectDataProvider ObjectType="{x:Type local:GetListOpremaNajem}"
                  MethodName="GetOprema" x:Key="getData">
<ObjectDataProvider.MethodParameters>
  <system:String>TextToSearch</system:String>
  <system:Integer>5</system:Integer>
</ObjectDataProvider.MethodParameters>
```

Object method:

```
public GetListOpremaNajem GetOprema(string searchText, UInt16 eID)
{
    if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(searchText)) 
    {
        return Databases.CallStoredOprema(currentConnSTRING, searchText, eID);
    } 
    else 
    {
        return new GetListOpremaNajem();
    }
}
```

But the following code returns nothing:

```
ObjectDataProvider _odProvider = new ObjectDataProvider();
_odProvider.ObjectType = typeof(GetListOpremaNajem);
_odProvider.MethodName = "GetOprema";
_odProvider.MethodParameters.Add("TextToSearch");
_odProvider.MethodParameters.Add(5);
this.DataContext = _odProvider;
```

When using only one parameter (i.e. `searchText`), it works well. How can I pass both parameters in code behind? I've searched the web and found no syntax for passing multiple parameters. What am I doing wrong? Thanks.

Comment: If you have code anyway you should not have much use for an `ObjectDataProvider` anyway.

Comment: It doesn't get hit at all. But it does when I use only one method parameter, i.e. _'public GetListOpremaNajem GetOprema(string searchText)'_ and adding only first parameter in the ObjectDataProvider instance.

Answer (score 1):

Replace this -

```
_odProvider.MethodParameters.Add(5);
```

with

```
_odProvider.MethodParameters.Add((UInt16)5);
```

Your method is not getting called since you are adding the `int` type in your parameter list but your method is expecting second parameter of type `UInt16`. So, type caste it to UInt16 and it should work fine then.

Comment: You are right. It was type cast between Integer and UInt16 type. Thanks a lot. It works fine.